# Custom functions or excel built-in features?

Tags: excel, vba

i came upon this and was wondering that those "formulas?" are.
Couldnt find anything similar to these expressions online

[image]

Comment: That is a named range. You can create your own named range. These can also be accessed from `Formulas Tab | Name Manager`

Comment: where can i find the "source" to those or edit them ?

Comment: I edited my comment above... `Formulas Tab | Name Manager`

Comment: You may also want to see [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)